# Sites reproducing content without attribution

Tags: support

There are sites out there reproducing DBA.se content without attribution.

http://www.faqssys.info/sqlplus-default-define-settings/ for example.

Do we need to report these, so they can be dealt with, or is this "syndication" best ignored?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Should have checked on meta.se before posting. My bad

Comment: No worries, it comes up often

Comment: @AaronBertrand is there a list of the already known SCRAPERs?

Comment: @dezso [Yes, here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules), though I don't think the list is being maintained any longer due to the new process. I don't know if there is an updated list anywhere.